# Computing a Galois action on elements as a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to understand how to realize Galois actions on roots via polynomials.

If we take the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ with generator $\sqrt{2}$ and minimal polynomial $f(x) = x^2 - 2$, we can see that the two roots are $\sqrt 2,-\sqrt 2$, and so the polynomial $\sigma(x) = -x$ realizes the Galois action by interchanging the two roots. It works the same way with $\sqrt{3}$.

Note that $\sigma$ is *not actually a field automorphism*, and that *it depends on the element* $\sqrt{2}$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. If we were acting on $a + b\sqrt{2}$, then we would need the polynomial $x \mapsto 2a - x$.

If we now take the larger field $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$, then we have the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space basis $\{1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}\}$ for $L$, and we can see that the Galois action is generated by $\sqrt{2} \mapsto -\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3} \mapsto -\sqrt{3}$, both of which are realized by the polynomial $\sigma(x)$.

However if we take the $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra generator $\alpha = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ for $L$, then although the Galois action on $\alpha$ is seen to flip the signs of the two terms, this action is generated now by the polynomials $\sigma(x) = -x$ and $\tau(x) = x^3 - 10x$.

How can one compute these polynomials $\sigma, \tau$? If we know all the conjugates of $\alpha$ under the Galois action, and using the fact that $\alpha$ generates $L/\mathbb{Q}$ as an algebra, then by expressing a conjugate $\bar{\alpha}$ in the basis $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3\}$, we will have found a polynomial for $\bar{\alpha}$ of degree $\leq 3$ in $\alpha$. What is the most efficient way to do this? Does it help to know that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $m(x) = x^4 - 10x^2 + 1$?

Given any element of $L$, I would like to be able to express the action on it by polynomials.

In some cases the polynomial will not be defined over the base field or the conjugates will not lie in the field extension. For example in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$, the action on $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is given by the linear polynomial $x \mapsto \zeta_3x$. But then what about the conjugates of the element $a + b\sqrt[3]{2} + c\sqrt[3]{4}$?

Answer (score 1):

You can think about them as the interpolation polynomials from a given permutation of $\alpha$ and its conjugates.

If you represent a permuation object as a set of points $\{(x_i,y_i)\}$, then the Galois group acts naturally on those sets, and the group also acts on the coefficients of the interpolating polynomial going through those points.
It turns out the action is the same in both case.

So you get rational coefficients if and only if the permutation you started with, as a set of couples of elements of $L$, is itself invariant by the Galois group. And if it is not, the coefficients have to live in the corresponding subfield.

Comment: Yes, I see that it is an interpolation polynomial. Is there an easier way to compute it in this case other than using Newton or Lagrange interpolation?

Comment: if you have numerical approximation for the roots AND you know how the Galois group acts on them, then it is pretty easy. If you don't well it is still as hard as finding the other roots as members of $\Bbb Q[\alpha]$, and it is highly nontrivial anyway.

Comment: So you're saying that the standard methods of polynomial interpolation are the easiest way to do this? There don't exist cleaner formulas due to the existence of the extra structure?

Comment: well here you can use ad. hoc reasoning, for example you can exploit the relation $(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3)(\sqrt 2 - \sqrt 3) = -1$ to get that the conjugates of $\alpha$ are $\pm \alpha^{\pm 1}$

Comment: Okay. But in general, not? Well shucks.